# Bhagavad-Gita: As It Is - version without interruptions?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, book-recommendation

I have read the Bhagavad-Gita: As It Is once before, and I would like to continue reading it. However, I find it very distracting to read it with the multi-page Purport sections between each verse. I love the Purport sections, but I wish I could read the Gita straight through without turning so many pages!

Is there a copy of the Gita: As It Is that has no Purport interruptions? Or is this the correct / only way - to have detailed explanations between each verse?

If not, can someone recommend a version that is just as strong a translation but without the Purport?

Thank you!

Comment: u can use vedabase.com and select chapterview. entire chapter is loaded in 1 page.

Comment: Which version (where) have you read (from) and what have you tried to search yourself?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Selecting view is better for RickSterling than selecting chapterview; chapterview shows the purports.

Comment: @iammilind What you're showing is "view".  This is "chapter-view": https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/1/chapter-view The regular view has no purports, whereas clicking chapter-view shows the purports as well.

Comment: @Keshav, you are right from URL perspective. But probably what Vishal meant by "chapter view" was the page which shows complete chapter Only with translations.  I was not aware that, they have a URL named with "chapter-view".

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan ya correct. view shows without purport. Chapter view is also customizable;there are various checkboxes on top to see the things you need. So we can just uncheck different checkboxes based on that.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg

Answer (score 7):

Issue with many such Gita-s is the translation problem. These translations were done with scarce resources & less availability of Sanskrit experts. In the current age of internet, this issue is resolved.

Here are few strategies:

1. Use [Gita supersite](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in) and choose the translations & purports you want. Only issue is, one need to go 1 by 1. IMO, translations by Gambhirananda is the closest among others & are neutral.
2. Use [Vedabase](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/1). Ignore translations & purports, but just look at breaking of each Sanskrit word & translate it yourself with http://spokensanskrit.de.

Purports are typically the interpretation of the author. You should read those, only if your mentality matches with the author. Otherwise interpret yourself.

<sub>IMPO, whichever way Gita is interpreted, is worth. The inclination is important. Interestingly
  - Some Nazi-s had their own interpretation of Gita, while committing crimes.

  - Some Muslim clerics have used Krishna's "do war" as a defence for some controversial  war related quotes of Quran.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> ### Is there a copy of the Gīta that has no purport interruptions?

Try [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0zBCVuV7cUDRJNTJIX01obG8/view) translation of Bhagavad-gītā by Gorakhpur Gita Press on Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0zBCVuV7cUDRJNTJIX01obG8/view

You cannot download or print it but you can **read it for free** at that link.

Here's a sample from the free e-book.

> [image]

---

> ### Why have detailed explanations between each verse?

Isn't the objective of any sacred text that you pick up to read or any other book for that matter to grasp complete and total knowledge from it? In the case of Gīta, what if you do not understand a verse (example: see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8735/2995), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11527/2995) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11520/2995))? Would you google for an in-depth explanation of the verse or rather have it all explained in the same book you were originally reading? The purport or commentary on the verses you find in books are meant for more advanced readers of the Gīta.

For more explanations, see answers under [How to start reading the Bhagavad-gītā?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5404/2995)

---

<sub>You can find other free e-books from Gorakhpur Gita Press in English and other languages at the link below.</sub>
<sub>http://gitapress.org/e-books.htm</sub>

<sub>DISCLAIMER: I'm not related to Gorakhpur Gita Press in anyway nor is this answer an advertisement.</sub>

Comment: The only hard copy of Gita I have is from Gorakhpur Gita press (it's in my native language Gujarati). That book contains only translations and is a pocket edition. Though it's better than Prabhupada or "as it is" at times, it's not loyal enough in word to word translations as much as Gambhirananda's. At many places they go over the words & change the meaning. IMO, let the interpretation (subjective) be whichever way, but the translations (objective) should be as perfect as possible without any inclination.

Comment: @iammilind Do you have a verse in mind where the translation of Gambirananda is better than others. I find Gorakhpur English tr. decent enough for beginners. I was comparing [BG 15.4](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=15&field_nsutra_value=4) - both Gambirananda and Gorakhpur guys use "I take refuge in that Primeval Person."

Comment: I've not known about ebook of English translation of Gita from Gitapress. Thanks! It will be useful for citation/reference also.

Comment: Not saying that it's a bad book. As I wrote above, that's the book I have in hard copy (apart from ISKCON, which I don't read) & I have referred for a long time. However, slowly when I delve into Sanskrit & read Gambhirananda's translations, I noticed significant differences from the actual verse. Like @Pandya, I was also not aware of its English online version. If that English version is similarly translated as Gujarati version, then you will notice lot of differences (including 15.4). Personally, I translate it myself & take Gambhirananda as reference. BTW, is the shared copy in drive legal?

Comment: @iammilind Yes, it's a legal copy, if you browse thru their ebooks link at the end of my answer, it takes you to their Google Drive.