# How many English translations are there of the Srimad Bhagavad Gita apart from the ''The Bhagavad Gita As it is''?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, translation-request

I am planning to read the Srimad Bhagavad Gita in English but I don't know which English version I should read. It would easier for me if somebody gave me the list of all English versions of the Bhagavad Gita. (No need to mention the ''Bhagavad Gita As it is'' version by A.C. Bhaktivedanta Srila Prabhupada)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bhagavad-Gita: As It Is - version without interruptions?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16176/bhagavad-gita-as-it-is-version-without-interruptions)

Comment: I think you want recommendations, not the list. The list can easily run into hundreds.

Comment: There are many many. My favorite is the translation by Swami Nikhilananda. It is in a small pocket book form easy to carry. Another is by Swami Gambhirananda with the commentary of Sankaracharya with both Sanskrit and English.

Comment: If you're a Vaishnava I suggest you to read two or three translations with a commentary by some Vaishnava translator and commentator. That can be important because a non-Vaishnava translators often translate some verses differently than Vaishnava translators, and their commentaries are much different than Vaishnava due to philosophical differences. The Prabhupada's edition has word by word translation of the verses which is good, and it has good Gaudiya Vaishnava commentary. Here is yet another Gaudiya version: http://nitaaiveda.com/Shrimad_Bhagavad_Gita/Gita_By_Acharyas.htm

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I would like to read Sri Vaishnava commentaries as well