# Is Gita from Yogananda a translation or commentary?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I'm looking for a Gita in English to replace the current version we have, which is the Bhagavad-Gita: As It Is by Parabhupāda.

I'm drawn to The Essence of Bhagavad Gita by Paramahansa Yogananda because I love his writing, but I cannot tell from the online descriptions whether this version is a translation or a commentary. If it is only commentary, I will look elsewhere for a Gita translation (likely Ghandi's transition).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bhagavad-Gita: As It Is - version without interruptions?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16176/bhagavad-gita-as-it-is-version-without-interruptions)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the above linked post. The question is whether Yogananda's version is a translation and if it is, whether the purports interrupt the narrative.

Comment: Do you want only the Bhagavad Gita commentary of Yogananda or any other commentators? Please make the title and body clear. The title asks something and the last line of the body says some other. The last line implies that you are asking a better translation without interruptions  and not the commentary. This gives to opinion based answers. So please be more accurate and edit the body and title..

Comment: @SS Versons of Yogananda commentary?? He has written only 1 version. I think you have messed his details.

Comment: @Rohit. No, I didn't. There is only one commentary. Yes. But OP was not aware whether it was a translation or a commentary. Even if it was a commentary, there could be variations with the publishers. E.g: There is only one Sri Bhashya but there are many versions based on the translators and the publishers. Similarly, here too. OP is seeking a book without interruptions of Yogananda's. That's why it's not a dupe of mentioned question.

Comment: Good work. you felt him better. @SS

Comment: @SS Thank you, you were correct. My original post contained a confusing ending which split the focus of my question and left it open for interpretation. I have made the requested edit and I am grateful to you for helping me see the consequence of a vague question. I will apply what you have said to my life entirely and not just this question.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a good decision to explore inner yogic meanings from the books of Yogananda. He has written a commentary on geeta which is named "God talks with Arjuna".  He has presented many practical aspects of inner rAja yoga in this book. You can slowly read one by one chapters and contemplate on its meanings. He has also described symbolism in this book.

You can download it from the below links or  buy from Amazon.

**[God talks with Arjuna - Part one](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.148952/2015.148952.The-Bhagavad-Gitachapter-1-5-Ed-1st#page/n0/mode/2up)**

**[God talks with Arjuna - Part two](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.463544)**

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will find that book as well. Do you know if "The Essence of Bhagavad Gita" by Yogananda is a Gita translation?

Comment: @user11647 "[The Essence of Bhagavad Gita](http://www.amazon.in/Essence-Bhagavad-Gita-Paramahansa-Remembered/dp/1565892267?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=9bb65aed-d3d0-4ae9-afd5-3aaf1f5d2f5a)" is not the work of Yogananda. It is written by Swami Kriyananda, the disciple of Yogananda.

Comment: Thank you - that is the info I am looking for. Did Yogananda ever translate the Bhagavad-Gita?

Comment: @user11647 please open the links and read the preface and forward.