# Best book on Bhagavat Gita?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, book-recommendation

Which is the most accurate English version of the Bhagavat Gita?

Comment: [Bhagavad Gita by Gita press Gorakhpur](https://gitapressbookshop.in/by-language/english/1658-shrimad-bhagvadgita-sanskrit-text-with-hindi-and-english-translation?sort=pd.name&order=ASC). They also sell the Bhashya by Adi Shankaracharya. Note the question being opinion based will be closed as per site rules. Welcome to HSE!

Comment: if you dont consider krishna as divine why read gita then.. Gita was told by krishna.. you  can leave gita for good because you can get the essence of teaching 1% of what krishna told..

Comment: @PrasannaR I am reading the Gita to analyse the philosphy behind it. It is a purely critical reading and plainly considering Krishna to be divine before I even read the Gita doesn't seem reasonable to me. This is just my subjective approach...

Comment: Welcome to our site:) But this is an "opinion based question". @AnanthaKrishnaK

Comment: @Rickross I have rewritten my question as 'Which is the most accurate English version of the Bhagavat Gita?'. I don't think that's opinion based.

Comment: There are other related questions here. [Bhagavad-Gita: As It Is - version without interruptions?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16176/bhagavad-gita-as-it-is-version-without-interruptions/) might answer your question.

Comment: Who's going to decide what's the most accurate version? A person? A committee? What if Person P1 considers Translation T1 as 'most accurate' and P2 says no, it's T2 which is the most accurate, which answer do you prefer? This is why your question cannot be answered objectively. However, you could ask something like, are there any translations which focus more on the message/philosophy than on divinity of Krishna.

Comment: No it's still opinion based because you are asking for the "most accurate" and the "best" translations and so answers will vary with person's opinions. @AnanthaKrishnaK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no most accurate or best version. All translations have some sort of bias. I am posting below some Gita translations that I have read.

Bhagavad Gita Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya translated by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier;

Gita translated by Radhakrishnan

Gita translated by Swami Tapasyananda

Universal Message of the Bhagavad Gita by Swami Ranganathananda